# What was bardic performance like in the D&D Next playtest?

Tags: bard, dnd-next-playtest

My RPG group is made up of players who had all played either 2nd or 3rd edition before, where bards had a combat-bonus ability significantly different than what's in D&D 5.  In both older versions, the bard was able to grant a combat bonus to all of its allies within earshot.

This was significantly changed for 5e, with bards instead being able to give their allies a "bonus die" which can only be used on a single roll.  The bonus is so different from what everyone's used to that, so far, no one's actually used the bardic inspiration die to modify a roll.

Based on statements like [this answer to "What changed between the playtest and 5e?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/41883/15655), it seems like for at least part of the playtest bards had a significantly different ability.  While we wait for whatever optional rule is (hopefully) in the DMG, can someone describe in broad strokes what the 5e "bardic performance" was like?

Comment: I wouldn't expect an optional rule for this in the DMG. A variation on a class feature isn't the sort of thing that's likely to appear there.

Comment: @Miniman unless we refer to the death cleric or oathbreaker paladin examples...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Public Playtest, which you can still get if you buy [one of the D&D Next modules](http://www.dndclassics.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_45190), it is called Bardic Performance. There were two abilities under Bardic Performance: *Call to Battle* and *Inspire Competence*.

*Call to Battle* allowed the Bard and his allies within 25 feet to add a d4 for damage. The die increased at higher levels.

*Inspire Competence* allowed the Bard's allies to add the Bard's proficiency bonus to one chosen ability check.

Comment: Interesting; that has changed.  What Call to Battle looks like is similar to the Cleric's spell *bless*