# Can D&DNext adventures be run in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

I wasn't paying attention to D&D during 5e development and so know nothing of the D&DNext ruleset: can D&DNext material be run in 5e? Or did the rules change enough that there'll be mechanics, stats, spells referenced in the Next material that won't make sense in 5e-land?

[What are the major differences between the final playtest package and D&D 5e Basic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41862/23970) describes some of the changes, but it doesn't quite hit my question. For instance, it mentions that proficiency bonuses are "now +2 to +6", but ithout knowing what they had been I can't guess as to whether numbers in published modules may need adjusting. That number, in particular, is both pretty impactful and pretty sensitive to alteration!

I guess I'm looking for report from anyone who's run Next-produced adventures in 5e of from anyone who's run those in Next and knows 5e well enough do speculate: **will it take converting/translating to run a Next adventure in 5e, or are adjustments at the level of usual play-time ad-libbing?**

Comment: [Highly related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41862/15469). Possibly even a duplicate, but I'm not willing to be the sole decider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the most part, yes you can run DnDnext content with the 5e rules. The biggest changes that you need to take into account is monster stats.  You will want to use the latest monster stats rather than those in the modules. In general the DnDNext monster stats were too low and did not pose much of a threat to players.

I ran all of the Next modules with the 5e rules and it was lots of fun, though many monsters were too weak to be much of a challenge.